# Peculiar use of return in function

Tags: c, return

I have a recursive function something peculiar, is this:

Did not know it can omit the *return*, the branch of "if" not return a valué but it works ¿I wonder if this is a valid behavior in C or compiler depends?

Comment: The `if()` path has no return path.  This is bad.  Save time: enable all compiler warnings or get new compiler as your complier should have told you this before needing to post on SO.

Comment: @chux did not read the question.  This is **not** a *"what is wrong with this code?"* question. This is *"Why does this strange, nearly invalid code still seem to work?"*

Comment: actually, the OPs code does not work.  Oh, it will do recursion, but the desired answer will not be produced.

Comment: here is the result of compiling your first function:  "badRecursion.c:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"   all compiles/links need to have all warnings enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative (note changed int to uint64_t):

```
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

uint64_t count(uint64_t num, uint64_t t)
{
    if (!num)
        return t;
    t +=  1ull << (num%10) * 6;
    return count(num / 10, t);
}
```

Same type of change for the second function:

```
int check(int min, int max, int num, int b, int t, int es)
{
    if(min > max)
        return es > 0 ? 1 : 0; 
    b = num / min;
    if (min * b == num && ((min % 10) || (b%10))
        && t == cant(min, 0) + cant(b, 0) )
        printf("%d = %d x %d\n", num, min, b), es++;
    return check(min + 1, max, num, b, t, es);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined behavior.

It generally works in most cases because `count` stores its return value in the normal location for return values (the `AX` register on the CPU), so the caller finds a return value, even though the function did not explicitly return a value.

However, this should be avoided.
It likely results in compiler warnings, and static analysis tools should always flag this as a serious problem.

---

The function can be simply fixed with:

```
int count(int num, int t)
{
    if (num)
    {
        t +=  1 << (num%10) * 6;
        return count(num / 10, t); // added the return keyword here.
    }
    else
        return t;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return statement is never mandatory, even in a function with a non-void return type. But if the return statement is omitted and the value is used by the caller then the behavior is undefined. There is one exception, in `main` if the return statement is omitted it as if there was a `return 0;`.

> (C99, 6.9.1p12) "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

In the particular case of your recursive `count` function, the return value is never accessed so calling the function does not invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes clear but I wonder how would the correct implementation of the function

Comment: The last sentence of the answer says it's a valid implementation of this function (with regards to the absence of the `return` statement). A least surprising implementation would change the statement `count(num / 10, t);` by this statement `return count(num / 10, t);`